# Using several JSONModel and XMLModel towards one component

Tags: sapui5

For a openui5 component I need to bind multiple models and is investigating what the best way to do this is.

The models are both JSONModel and XMLModel.

The background is that I want provide the user choice of multiple source to use for the custom openui5-spitz-reader component https://github.com/elsewhat/openui5-spritz-reader

Each of the selection the user can make (BBC World News, Reddit /r/worldnews), has a single Model populated.

During runtime, I need to combine all the Models the user has selected and bind the combined content towards the items aggregation of the openui5-spitz-reader component.

Answer (score 2):

You can use named models on aggregations see [Multimodel Support](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/UsageInApp.html) - example using multiple models on an element [JSBin OData Model dynamic column and data binding](http://jsbin.com/howip/4/edit)

I am not sure if you can bind data from 2 models on a single aggregation, you may be able to achieve it using a [factory function](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/BindingAggregations.html) with the aggregation or a handler on the model binding - [using a generic binding to sum aggregation](http://jsbin.com/fepud/1/edit)